# clojure.lang.RT thread-safe?

Tags: clojure

I am using **clojure.lang.RT** (with clojure-1.4.0.jar) to evaluate at runtime a number of scripts supplied by the end-users of the application, doing things like:

```
return (Boolean) RT.var("clojure.core", "eval").invoke(RT.var("clojure.core", "read-string").invoke(script))
```

... and:

```
IFn fn = (IFn) RT.var("clojure.core", "eval").invoke(RT.var("clojure.core", "read-string").invoke(script))
```

Given the **var** method is static can I assume that the above uses of the **clojure.lang.RT** API are thread-safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calls to RT.var are as thread safe as the script you are invoking. If you ran two scripts that each changed some var by calling `def` or `defn` the two scripts could get mutually inconsistent views of the contents of the vars. In general this is very likely to be safe though.